# searching files from a lot of files for a keyword and printing the sentence containing keyword,filename in python

Tags: python, string

```
import os
path = 'C:\\Users\\Kabeer\\Documents\\testdata'
listing = os.listdir(path)
for infile in listing:
   read_f = open(infile)
   for line in read_f:
    if 'arch' in line:
     print(line)
print ("current file is: " + infile)
```

I have placed all the files in a folder. I want to read each file for a keyword. If it contains the keyword then print the name of file and entire sentence containing keyword.

I am absolute beginner in python. The code above is also picked from stackoverflow forum only.

I am getting error. File not found error read_f=open(infile).No such file or directory.

I know error is in loop. How to put each file through loop? I tried also putting all the files in list. But I am not able to get each file and read from loop.

Thanks

Kabeer

Comment: post the value of `listing` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use `read_f = open(os.path.join(path,infile))`

Comment: It is working for test cases. These are text files. This had stopped my work for 5 days.@Avinash Raj- I have not tried your solution as listing is not variable.